# The relation of order of finite cyclic group and its generator

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

My question is how to prove a finite cyclic group $G$ has order (i.e. size) $n$ if and only if each of its generator has order $n$.
Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried? If we know what you're struggling with, we can better help you ^_^

Comment: @HallaSurvivor I am quite confuse that how to start the proof, I have tried to assume $g$ to be a generator with order $n$ of the finite cyclic group $G={g^1,g^2,...,g^n}$. But I don't know how to finish the proof